# Getting NULL when trying to read property file Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I have **Employee** Class, which contains utility methods.

```
@Service
    public class Employee {

        @Value("${Employee.name}")
        private String firstName;

        List<String> employees = Arrays.asList(firstName);

        public List<String> allEmplyees() {
            System.out.println("First Name ::" + firstName);
            return employees;
        }

        public int numberOfEmployees() {
            return employees.size();
        }
    }
```

I am reading the property file in the Employee class & using values in methods.

I have a second class Consumer, which Autowires **Employee** class and calls its methods.
**Problem**: 
I am getting **[null]**, when i am calling *allEmployees* method from Consumer class.
**Example:**

**Consumer Class**

```
@RestController
public class StudentController {
@Autowired
    private Employee employee;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test")
    public String testMe(){
        return employee.allEmplyees().toString();

    }
}
```

What I a doing wrong, please help!!

Comment: second class is Consumer class.

Comment: i have updated the code.

Comment: @Deadpool:  I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<String> employees = Arrays.asList(firstName);
```

Arrays.asList() will return an ArrayList which is a private static class inside Arrays, it is not the java.util.ArrayList class.
To add more, `@Value` annotations are processed once the bean is created. so you could use `@PostConstruct` to set the instance variables after spring injects the `@Value` fields or put it as an argument to the constructor.

```
    private List<String> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.employees.add(firstName);
    }
```

or

```
    private String firstName;

    List<String> employees = null;


    public Employee(@Value("${Employee.name}") String name) {
        this.firstName = name;
        this.employees = Arrays.asList(firstName);
    }
```